# I would like to make listener contract

Tags: smart-contract

I would like to make a contract, wich listens to the incoming transfers.

How do I make a listener contract, wich listens to incoming transfers on the account?

Comment: Oh i see.. I need to modify the transfer contract.

Comment: Hi @efraim, you should write an answer and accept it, so others with a similar problem who will find this question in the future will see the solution. Ideally add some code example to show what you did.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is:

1 I modify the eosio token contract. First I put the new method wich we want to run after the transfer contract. Forexample: after_transfer (){....}

2. After I put the these lines to the their *.hpp

[[eosio::on_notify("*::transfer")]] void after_transfer(eosio::name from, eosio::name to, eosio::asset quantity, std::string memo);

This is  modify eosio token contract. I deployed to the eos account. So if somewhere use transfer method..(transfer token to account wich contain the modify transfer method)  after the transfer run the second method (after_transfer())

The solution is a "eosio::on_notify".